# Are JS nested callbacks allowed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run an w3schools example for JS callbacks, it runs OK for the first callback and shows "The paragraph is now hidden OK", but NOT the second alert, what I'm doing wrong? or nested callbacks are not allowed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){    
        $("p").hide("slow", function(){        
            alert("The paragraph is now hidden OK", function(){            
                 alert("2nd alert FAIL");
            });
        });
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Hide</button>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1:**
what I need to do for made my custom function callback supported?

**EDIT 2**

**Solved**, donig a Function Callback supported just:

```
​// A function that takes two parameters, the last one a callback function​
​function getInput (options, callback) {
    allUserData.push (options);
    callback (options);
​
}
```

Comment: you can use confirm to get user input or you can simply use two alerts.

Comment: Where have you ever seen an `alert()` which takes a function as a second argument?  "Nested callbacks" certainly are allowed, primarily because there's really no such construct as "nested callbacks".  All you're doing is providing function objects as arguments to function calls which expect them.  But the function has to *expect it*.  You can't arbitrarily re-define how existing functions work just by adding more arguments to them.

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate for HTML, CSS & JS.

Comment: ^^ MDN = https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web Note that MDN is collaboratively, community edited, and so it does sometimes have the odd error -- but the community is good at fixing them when they arise. (If you don't primarily read the English version of it, unfortunately you do sometimes want to double-check the English version of an article, as those tend to get more updates.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) doesn't offer a callback. `alert` is a 1990s anachronism which brings the browser's main JavaScript thread to a screeching halt while the alert is showing, so in that particular case, just put the code you currently have in the callback *after* the `alert`. (Or better yet: Don't use `alert`. :-) ) `alert` (and `prompt` and `confirm`) are anachronistic exceptions to the overall "don't block the thread" rule.

No reason the other callbacks, which are also nested, wouldn't work. And indeed they do:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){    
        $("p").hide("slow", function(){        
            alert("The paragraph is now hidden OK");
            alert("2nd alert FAIL");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<button>Hide</button>
<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fun fact: the spec allows [`alert` to be non-blocking](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert): _"Optionally, pause while waiting for the user to acknowledge the message."_

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Maybe it's the first step in a slow evolution toward bringing `alert` and such into the non-blocking fold. (Though it's hard to see how `prompt` and `confirm` could be. But `alert`...) Allow it in the spec, then update user agents to let the user choose to make it that way, then make that the default but with the option of choosing the old behavior, then...remove the old behavior entirely. One can hope. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `alert()` method cannot take in a function. Only a string or object can be displayed. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)

Answer (score 0):

Nested callbacks are allowed, but are usually not encouraged (makes the code more difficult to read).

However the issue you have, is that `alert` does not take a callback, it only takes one parameter (see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp )

This code should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){    
        $("p").hide("slow", function(){        
            alert("The paragraph is now hidden OK");
            alert("2nd alert FAIL");
        });
    });
});
```